# Have my code act as a p tag and not as a link if there is no URL

Tags: angularjs

I am relatively new to angularJs so I am trying to learn how to do different things. I have been trying to make solutionName act as a p tag if there is no URL input for solutionUrl1, at the moment solutionName is acting as if it is hyperlinked even when its not. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <a ng-href="{{::data.solutionUrl1}}" class="card__title" style="text-align: center">
        <span>{{::data.solutionName}}</span>
    </a>
```

Comment: Why would you want to learn AngularJS when support for this frameworks ends in a couple of months? Why not focused on angular, the successor?

Comment: My current job uses angluarjs. Since then I have been studying how to become better at it. However, I totally agree with you, is Angularjs code compatible with Angular code? Or is there much of a difference?

Comment: Not compatible at all. If your company doesn't want to switch to angular, it will get harder to maintain and to get developers for it. But that's beside the question, I will try to post an approach for solving your problem tomorrow.

Comment: You could use  `ng-if`

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng-if of angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) to render either one or the other:

Something like this, you most probably have to change the condition to meet your needs. You can also create a new Variable in the JS files like `showLink` and set this variable to true/false depending on some conditions. And then just use this boolean variable to show/hide the link with the method outlined below:

```
<div ng-if="data.solutionUrl1">
    <!-- code to render the link-->
</div>
<div ng-if="!data.solutionUrl1">
    <!-- code to render just the span without the link -->
</div>
```